# How do I create a PassthroughSubject that can have an output of any type?

Tags: swift, casting, combine

I would like to create a PassthroughSubject object that can send an output of any type. In code I currently have something like this:

```
let cmd1Subj = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()
let cmd2Subj = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()
var desiredCmd: PassthroughSubject<String, Never>?
let executeDesiredCmdSubj = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()
var arg: String?

func executeDesiredCmd(cmdArg: String) -> AnyPublisher<String, Never> {
    guard (desiredCmd != nil) else {
        return Just("Nothing to execute\n").eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    desiredCmd?.send(cmdArg)
    return Just("Executed: \(String(describing: desiredCmd)) with argument: \(cmdArg)").eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

let cancellable = executeDesiredCmdSubj
    .flatMap(executeDesiredCmd)
    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
    .sink(receiveValue: {
        print($0)
    })

desiredCmd = cmd1Subj
arg = "This is the argument for command 1"
desiredCmd?.send(arg!)
desiredCmd = cmd2Subj
arg = "This is the argument for command 2"
desiredCmd?.send(arg!)
```

How do I change `desiredCmd` and `executeDesiredCmdSubj` such that they can send an output of any type, as determined at runtime? I'd like to do something like this:

```
let cmd1Subj = PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>()
let cmd2Subj = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()
var desiredCmd: PassthroughSubject<Some_Generic_Type, Never>?
let executeDesiredCmdSubj = PassthroughSubject<Some_Generic_Type, Never>()
var arg: Some_Generic_Type?

func executeDesiredCmd(cmdArg: Some_Generic_Type) -> AnyPublisher<String, Never> {
    guard (desiredCmd != nil) else {
        return Just("Nothing to execute\n").eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    desiredCmd?.send(cmdArg)
    return Just("Executed: \(String(describing: desiredCmd)) with argument: \(cmdArg)").eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

let cancellable = executeDesiredCmdSubj
    .flatMap(executeDesiredCmd)
    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
    .sink(receiveValue: {
        print($0)
    })

desiredCmd = cmd1Subj
arg = 12345
desiredCmd?.send(arg!)
desiredCmd = cmd2Subj
arg = "This is the argument for command 2"
desiredCmd?.send(arg!)
```

where **Some_Generic_Type** is a placeholder that can be used to represent any type I attempt to pass through my PassthroughSubject. I tried using "Any" as the placeholder but it produces a couple of compilation errors:

- "Cannot assign value of type 'PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>' to type 'PassthroughSubject<Any, Never>"
- "Cannot assign value of type 'PassthroughSubject<String, Never>' to type 'PassthroughSubject<Any, Never>"

Comment: That's not what a generic is. `MyGeneric<Any>` does not somehow embrace `MyGeneric<Int>`. They are entirely unrelated types. Thus, this proposition is meaningless.

Comment: @matt I've updated the wording of my question. I'm not necessarily intent on using "Any" as an all-encompassing type. I was just demonstrating code that I've tried. Is there a way to accomplish what I'm looking for?

Comment: That's a great question. What are you looking for? So far it seems like you're looking for the ability to pass String-Or-Int as the value that comes down the pipeline, and _that_ is something I know how to do

Comment: @matt Yes that's exactly what I'm looking for. I would like to pass an Int, a String, a Bool (and sometimes nothing, i.e. Void). But I won't know the type I'm passing until runtime. I've demonstrated a possible use case in my code above where "desiredCmd" is first set to cmd1Subj, a PassthroughSubject that has Int output, and then "desiredCmd" is set to cmd2Subj, a PassthroughSubject that has String output. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do this by creating a struct that defines a couple of enums with associated values:

```
struct VersatilePassthroughSubject {
    enum SubjectOutputType {
        case subjAsStringOutput(PassthroughSubject<String, Never>)
        case subjAsIntOutput(PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>)
    }
    
    enum Arg {
        case argAsString(String)
        case argAsInt(Int)
    }
    
    var subj: SubjectOutputType? = nil
    var arg: Arg? = nil
}

let cmd1Subj = PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>()
let cmd2Subj = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()
var desiredCmd: VersatilePassthroughSubject = VersatilePassthroughSubject()
let executeDesiredCmdSubj = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()

func executeDesiredCmd() -> AnyPublisher<String, Never> {
    guard (desiredCmd.subj != nil) else {
        return Just("Nothing to execute\n").eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    if case .subjAsIntOutput(let subj) = desiredCmd.subj {
        if case .argAsInt(let arg) = desiredCmd.arg {
            subj.send(arg)
            return Just("Executed: \(String(describing: desiredCmd)) with argument: \(arg)").eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
    }
    else if case .subjAsStringOutput(let subj) = desiredCmd.subj {
        if case .argAsString(let arg) = desiredCmd.arg {
            subj.send(arg)
            return Just("Executed: \(String(describing: desiredCmd)) with argument: \(arg)").eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
    }
    return Just("Nothing to execute\n").eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

let cancellable = executeDesiredCmdSubj
    .flatMap(executeDesiredCmd)
    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
    .sink(receiveValue: {
        print($0)
    })

desiredCmd.subj = .subjAsIntOutput(cmd1Subj)
desiredCmd.arg = .argAsInt(12345)
executeDesiredCmdSubj.send()
desiredCmd.subj = .subjAsStringOutput(cmd2Subj)
desiredCmd.arg = .argAsString("This is the argument for command 2")
executeDesiredCmdSubj.send()
```

Comment: Not quite how I would have done it, but yes, an enum-as-union is the way to go.